# android devices can't be recognized in adb on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu

i install ubuntu on one mac mini, but when i connected my android devices, it can only recognized some of them. i connect 5 devices, it can only recognized 3 or 4.

output of lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 2717:9039  
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 2717:9039  
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 2717:9039  
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 2717:9039  
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 2717:9039
```

output of adb devices

```
List of devices attached 
434c05cc        offline
10549306        offline
4c13cb2f        offline
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your PC hasn"t USB Vendor IDs of devices

Look at this page: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: But my pc can recognize some of them,not all of them. and i have try this on my dell pc(also ubuntu 14.04x64), it can recognize all of them. and i have type this command:`android update adb`

Comment: it is possible. try to add udev rules for unrecognized devices.

Comment: I have already add 51-andoird.rules at /etc/udev/rules.d/, but it seems that this is not useful.